# Function only being passed to React child component once

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've got something I don't understand here.  I'm creating a hierarchy of React functional components like so:

```
const ContainerComponent = () => {
  const [total, setTotal] = useState(initialValue);
  const updateFunction = () => { console.log('It got called'); }

  return (
    <EntryComponent updateFunction={updateFunction} />
  );
}

const EntryComponent = ({updateFunction}) => {
  const services = [{}, {}, {}];

  return (
    {services.map((service) => <ServiceComponent updateFunction={updateFunction} />}
  );
}

const ServiceComponent = ({updateFunction}) => {
  return (
    <input type='checkbox' onChange={updateFunction} ></input>
  );
}
```

So the idea is that the function gets passed all the way to the `ServiceComponent` and attached to the checkbox for each component.  On change the function should fire, running the code and updating the `total` value in the `ContainerComponent`.  Problem is that this isn't happening properly and the function seems only to be passed to the first `ServiceComponent` instance.  If I drop a `console.log(updateFunction)` into `ServiceComponent` I see the function logged for the first component, and `undefined` for the remaining two.  This is strange even for JavaScript.  Can anyone shed any light as to what is going on?  As far as I understand the function should be able to be passed like any other variable, and each `ServiceComponent` should have it to use when needed.  Indeed, if I pass a second property to the child, an object or a primitive like an integer it comes through just fine on every child component.  Why is this not occurring for my function, and how do I fix it?

Edit:  I see the problem, and the problem is I'm not as smart as I think I am.  In the condensed version I put here everything is being supplied to the child components in the same loop, but in the actual project the child components are created in multiple places and I neglected to pass the function property to all of them.  Which is mind mindbogglingly stupid on my part.  I'm leaving the question here as many of you have posted replies, for which I'm grateful.

Programming is hard, I think I need a better brain.

Comment: the code you pasted just works on my end
https://codesandbox.io/s/late-feather-vqvfng?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Yeah this is odd, the problem is likely elsewhere. Mind pasting less pseudocode? It's hard to imagine how something passed as a prop to a single component, then mapped/passed to other child components, could result in the behavior you describe (undefined for a prop for a mapped subset.).  It's mind boggling a primitive works and a function doesn't. There must be something else going on here than the code above. Subscribed for updates..

Comment: Yeah, it does work doesn't it.  That's because the code I posted here is just fine, while the (much larger) components I'm working with locally are more complex and the child components are being rendered in multiple places.  Like an idiot I wasn't passing the function prop to all of them; changing that fixes the problem.  Thank you all for your assistance, sorry for not being as careful with this as I should have been.

Answer (score 1):

I tried refactoring your code to this

```
const ContainerComponent = () => {
  const [total, setTotal] = useState(0);
  const updateFunction = (e) => {
    console.log("update total stuff happens here");
    console.log(e);
  };

  return <EntryComponent updateFunction={updateFunction} />;
};

const EntryComponent = ({ updateFunction }) => {
  const services = ["one", "two", "three"];

  return (
    <>
      {services.map((service) => (
        <ServiceComponent updateFunction={updateFunction} />
      ))}
    </>
  );
};

const ServiceComponent = ({ updateFunction }) => (
  <input type="checkbox" onChange={updateFunction}></input>
);
```

and it works just fine.
Try also using a react fragment in your entry component.